# Delphi ShortInt helper ToString with const

Tags: delphi, constants, helper

I have some constants in a separate unit, I can't do a .ToString on these constants if type is ShortInt (< 128).

Example : 
Create Unit and add:

```
const abc = 127;
```

Create a TForm and in FormShow do:

```
Edit1.Text := abc.tostring;
```

Did you know why it didn't work ?
**Type record, object, or class required** ..

It works if a constant is in the same unit..

Comment: What about the good old inttoStr()?

Comment: Is the unit where `abc` is declared contained in the uses clause of your form?

Comment: IntToStr work perfectly, yes the unit with the consts is contained in the uses of my form.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce this with the following minimal example

**Program1.dpr**

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas';

begin
  Writeln(abc.ToString);
end.
```

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

const
  abc = 127;

implementation

end.
```

This is a clear compiler bug. You can work around the problem with an inelegant type hint like this:

```
const
  abc = Shortint(127);
```

This suggests to me that when there is not type hint, the compiler sees `127` as something other than `Shortint`. I'm not quite sure what though, because I cannot see inside the compiler.

Please submit a bug report to Embarcadero.

Comment: Thanks you I will do it, RSP-16798 on Embarcadero quality.

Comment: Please use the [MCVE] from my answer because that will make it easier for Embarcadero to understand the problem. It is worthwhile referencing this question in your bug report too.